# Why pointers are not used in embedded c frequently?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

I come across that question in one of my interviews. Can anyone
please provide the advantages and disadvantages of using pointers in embedded C?

Comment: In regards to embedded devices, memory is usually a bottleneck resource that has to be managed very tightly. You will frequently have to balance the RAM you have available between the stack, the statics, and the heap (where allocated memory comes from). Typically you'll want to design your stack and statics to cover everything you need, and that doesn't leave much room for the heap. So relying on dynamically allocated memory could cause serious issues with your design.

Comment: Interview questions don't always have definitive correct answers - a well designed question will invite a dialogue about a particular topic.

Comment: This may have been an attempt to see if the candidate can describe the strict aliasing rule. However, either the question was badly phrased, or you did not paraphrase it correctly.

Comment: There's some old notion from the 8 bit MCU era (1980s-1990s) that pointers should be avoided in embedded systems for performance reasons. Pointers _did_ result in significantly worse code on old, bad 8-bitter compilers. We are talking about compilers that barely did any form of optimization and certainly not function inlining.

Comment: Other than that, telling a C programmer to write a program without using pointers is like telling a carpenter to build furniture without using nails or screws. Sure, they _might_ pull it off by using wooden plugs or some such, but the result will be much more contrived, expensive and cumbersome.

Comment: It is a nonsense - I have been building embedded systems for 32 years and pointers are used extensively - it would be difficult not to.  Some inexperienced C developers seem to think that pointers are only related to dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`) which is of course nonsense, but the use of dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems is a subject of that might deserve discussion.

Comment: @akatzt ... but the question is about pointers, not about dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 8):

The interview question is rubbish.  Embedded systems use pointers all the time.

I think the intended discussion point is that Embedded Systems *sometimes* have quite low amounts of memory.  It's *not usual* in these systems to do the typical memory allocation (`malloc()`/`free()`) routines used in system/applications-level programming.    The interview question is confusing "using pointers" with "allocating dynamic memory" (probably on purpose).

On an embedded system, commonly all the memory the program will ever use is statically allocated.

Of course there's a lot of *it depends* here too.  An [Attiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATtiny_microcontroller_comparison_chart) has only a kilobyte or so of RAM, whereas a something like an [STM32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32) has many times more.

EDIT: And the [Propeller](https://www1.parallax.com/microcontrollers/propeller) can have 512k/1MiB.   Note that this is much more memory than plenty of workstations had during the 1980's and early 90's.

Comment: All good, but note that memory availability is not the only, or even the necessarily the most important issue relating to dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems.  Heap allocation and deallocation typically has non-deterministic execution time which is a disaster in hard-real-time systems.

Comment: Even if the embedded system has a lot of RAM, it may be set up with no dynamic memory allocation for other reasons.  Without dynamic memory allocation, it is more predictable/reliable.  Also, not all embedded systems have a memory manager available.  And, since they work within more limited parameters than, say, a web or PC application, there is less *need* for dynamic memory allocation in order to efficiently implement a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not really clear. You use pointers when you need them, but they cannot really be avoided. First, let's consider this simple hello world:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world");
}
```

`"Hello world"` is a string literal, and those have the type char array. And whenever you pass an array to a function, the array decays to a *pointer*.

So, as you can see. Even for the most trivial programs, it's essentially impossible to code C without pointers.

I can technically write programs without using pointers, but I have actually no idea for how to do any input or output without them.